# Theoretically, how could a wormhole be made?

Tags: general-relativity, topology, wormholes

Concentrating a lot of matter in one place will make a black hole, not a wormhole. A wormhole would change the topology of spacetime. Does General Relativity allow this?

I know there are wormhole solutions to GR field equations, but they are static solutions. Is there a time evolving solution to the GR equations in which a flat region of spacetime transforms into a wormhole geometry/topology due to an appropriate inflow of matter and energy and negative energy?

What determines where the other mouth of the wormhole forms?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a wormhole be created if it has not always existed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/537994/can-a-wormhole-be-created-if-it-has-not-always-existed)